# How does skin width work in Unity's CharacterController?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics

I'm trying to write my own character controller and I want to understand how Unity's works. I think what it does is this: at each fixed update it takes the smaller collider reduced by the skin width, casts it forward to see where it hits something, then moves the character forward so that the full size collider touches that point. So my first question is is that right, am I missing an important step?

My next question is how does `Physics.SphereCast` work? What subroutines and geometric algorithms are involved? Every `Collider` has the methods `Raycast`, `ClosestPoint`, and `ClosestPointOnBounds`, so does `Physics.SphereCast` just use some combination of those functions for each `Collider`, or is there more math involved on top of that? And are sphere casting and capsule casting the main geometric algorithms used by the character controller, or are there others I should be aware of?

Comment: These seem to be two unrelated questions. Please ask them separately. Note that we generally cannot tell you how Unity's implementations work beyond the published C# source code, but we can help you solve problems in your own implementation if you frame your question in those terms

Comment: I've seen the published source code but I found it hard to navigate. Do you have any advice on how to read it easier? Perhaps I just need a better IDE

Comment: Sounds like something you might want to discuss in [chat].